# how to capture image from Camera in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have made an application to capture photos from the camera.

I have created two Activities: In Activity1 there is one Button which starts the camera wehen it is clicked. When the image is captured, it is passed to Activity2.

However, when I run the application and start the Activity1 (with the one Button) and I click on the button to start the camera it displays a pop up window showing the message "Unfortunately, camera has stopped". There are no errors in the log-cat or on the console.

Can anyone help me. Please. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need only one Activity if you use startActiviyForResult():

Bello, a simple source code for take a picture from camera app, you need to start Activity with startActiviyForResult() and receive the intent from camera application.

Java source code:

```
package com.example.coursandroid_chp;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class MediaActivity extends Activity {

        private static final String TAG = "MediaActivity";
        private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
        private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 2;
        private Button mCameraPhotoButton;
        private Button mCameraVideoButton;
        private ImageView mPhotoImageView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.screen_media);
            mCameraPhotoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.screen_media_camera_photo_button);
            mCameraVideoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.screen_media_camera_video_button);
            mPhotoImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.screen_media_photo_imageview);
            mCameraPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
            mCameraVideoButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.screen_media, menu);
            return true;
        }

        private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.screen_media_camera_photo_button:
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    break;
                case R.id.screen_media_camera_video_button:
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE), REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {

                switch (resultCode) {
                case RESULT_OK:
                    Log.v(TAG, "Picture taken! :)");
                    if (data != null) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
                        mPhotoImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                    break;
                case RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Log.v(TAG, "Picture canceled! :(");
                    break;
                }
            } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE) {

                switch (resultCode) {
                case RESULT_OK:
                    Log.v(TAG, "Video taken! :)");
                    break;
                case RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Log.v(TAG, "Video canceled! :(");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }



Xml layout file


 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MediaActivity" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/screen_media_camera_photo_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="Camera photo" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/screen_media_camera_video_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/screen_media_camera_photo_button"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:text="Camera video" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/screen_media_photo_imageview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/screen_media_camera_video_button"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bitmap" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code :

```
package com.example.sample1;


import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CapturePhotoSample1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{


    public static final int TAKE_PHOTO=1; 
    ImageView imageView=null;

    private File folder;
    String imageFileName=null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_photo_sample1);

        Button button=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.capture_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button=null;

        imageView=(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.image_view1);

        folder = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ "/sample1/");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }


    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,actionCode);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int id=v.getId();

        if(id==R.id.capture_button)
            this.dispatchTakePictureIntent(TAKE_PHOTO);
    }

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);

        return true;

    }

    public void handleCameraPhoto(Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
        Bitmap bitmap=(Bitmap)extras.get("data");
        this.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        if(this.isExternalStorageAvailable())
        {
            this.imageFileName="img_"+SDUtil.now(-1)+".png"; 

                    /*SDUtil.now() is our own library.It is for creating file name with respect to data and time.IF u copy the hole program means sdutil shows error.For that you write a logic for creating a file name. */

            String path=folder+"/"+this.imageFileName;

            FileOutputStream fos=null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos=null;

            try
            {
                fos=new FileOutputStream(path);
                bos=new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bos);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(bos!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    bos.flush();
                    //bos.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(bos!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    bos.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            if(fos!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fos.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            bos=null;
            fos=null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            if(requestCode==TAKE_PHOTO)
            {
                handleCameraPhoto(data);
            }
        }


    }

    private boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {

        StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath());
        double sdAvailSize = (double) stat.getAvailableBlocks()
                * (double) stat.getBlockSize();
        // One binary gigabyte equals 1,073,741,824 bytes.
        double mbAvailable = sdAvailSize / 1048576;

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
        boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // We can read and write the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            // We can only read the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        } else {
            // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but
            // all we need
            // to know is we can neither read nor write
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        }

        if (mExternalStorageAvailable == true
                && mExternalStorageWriteable == true && mbAvailable > 10) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Error is showing on this line (import com.ivy.lib.SDUtil;). How to import SDTUtil ?

Answer (score 1):

The steps are:

**1.** So First of all as before we need to create a static int that will be our

```
public static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1777;
```

**2.** Next we fire  intent to start Activity for result:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Here we are actually passing an **URI** as an extra to the intent in order to save the image at this location when it will be taken.

**3.** Finally we will receive the result in `onActivityResult`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{  
    //Check that request code matches ours:
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) 
    {
        //Get our saved file into a bitmap object:
       File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
       Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 1000, 700);
    }
}
```

When `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile` method is:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
{ // BEST QUALITY MATCH
    
    //First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight) 
    {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
    }
    int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

    if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) 
    {
        //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
    }

    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

don't forget to add the relevent camera permissions to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: Your blog is dead or at least the link is broken. Perhaps you should remove the link from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

make sure to add permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

if that doesn't fix youre problem than u should show us youre code

Comment: It does not need any permissions if he calls the native camera app. It is the camera that take the picture, not the own app. you need camera permissions if you want to acces on camera api.

Comment: the camera permission he won't need, however i was working on a camera-app myself and i did found some post where they said to add the permissions because of problems by some devices. never could test this but just added it to be sure. and he needs to be able to save his images, dont he?

Answer (score 1):

check below code in your activity

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{ 
    //Check that request code matches ours:
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    { //Check if your application folder exists in the external storage, if not create it:
        your code should be here..... 
        //Check if data in not null and extract the Bitmap:
        if (data != null)
        {
            String filename = "image";
            String fileNameExtension = ".jpg";
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String imageStorageFolder = File.separator+"Your application Folder"+File.separator;
            File destinationFile = new File(sdCard, imageStorageFolder + filename + fileNameExtension);
            Log.d(TAG, "the destination for image file is: " + destinationFile );
            if (data.getExtras() != null)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                try
                {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR:" + e.toString());
                }
            }}}
```